# Duplicating rows in an oracle query

Tags: oracle

I am to create a query which will be used for printing labels in our project and find it difficult since the count of the number of labels is based on a string. I have made a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  wipdatavalue
  , containername
  , l
  , q as qtybox
  , d
  , qtyperbox AS q
  , productname
  , dt
  , dsn
  , CASE
      WHEN instr(wipdatavalue, '-') = 0
        THEN
          to_number(wipdatavalue)
      ELSE
          to_number(substr(wipdatavalue, 1, instr(wipdatavalue, '-') - 1))
    END AS una
  , CASE
      WHEN instr(wipdatavalue, '-') = 0 
        THEN
          to_number(wipdatavalue)
      ELSE
        to_number(substr(wipdatavalue, instr(wipdatavalue, '-') + 1))
    END AS dulo  
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY containername) AS n
  , count(*) over() m
FROM trprinting_ls
WHERE containername = 'TRALTESTU0A'
GROUP BY wipdatavalue, containername, l, q, d, qtyperbox, productname, dt, dsn
ORDER BY wipdatavalue
```

The query above will result to below:

[image]

But actually, I have to display the first Item (Wipdatavalue 1-4) not only once but four times to look something like this:

[image]

I have tried another query that runs fine but when I try to load it in our project, it does not print the label. We found out that it is because of the WITH statement and we don't know why. The query is:

```
WITH DATA (WIPDATAVALUE, CONTAINERNAME, L, Q, D, QTYBOX, PRODUCTNAME, DT, una, dulo, m1, n)
     AS (SELECT WIPDATAVALUE, CONTAINERNAME, L, Q, D, QTYBOX, PRODUCTNAME, DT, una, dulo,(dulo - una) + 1 AS m1,una n
           FROM (SELECT WIPDATAVALUE, CONTAINERNAME, L, Q, D, QTYPERBOX AS QTYBOX, PRODUCTNAME, DT,
                        CASE
                          WHEN instr(wipdatavalue, '-') = 0
                          THEN
                            to_number(wipdatavalue)
                          ELSE
                            to_number(substr(wipdatavalue, 1, instr(wipdatavalue, '-') - 1))
                          END AS una,
                          CASE
                            WHEN instr(wipdatavalue, '-') = 0 
                            THEN
                              to_number(wipdatavalue)
                            ELSE
                              to_number(substr(wipdatavalue, instr(wipdatavalue, '-') + 1))
                          END AS dulo
                   FROM trprinting_ls
                  WHERE containername = 'TRALTESTU0A'
                  )
         UNION ALL
         SELECT WIPDATAVALUE, CONTAINERNAME, L, Q, D, QTYBOX, PRODUCTNAME, DT, una, dulo, m1, n + 1
           FROM DATA
          WHERE n + 1 <= dulo)
SELECT WIPDATAVALUE, CONTAINERNAME, L, Q, D, QTYBOX, PRODUCTNAME, DT, una, dulo, n,
       count(*) OVER () m
FROM DATA
ORDER BY n, wipdatavalue
```

Thanks guys for helping out.

Comment: please share table structure and some sample data if possible...

Comment: Hello Vineet, i dont have access for the table structure. As for the sample data, I have it on the image above. If you need any other things, please let me know.

Comment: Why do you need the `group by` in the first query? recurcieve CTEs (2nd query) are only in oracle 11gR2 is that what you're using

Comment: Hi A.B. Cade, I am using the group by expression since I'm counting all the total number of returned rows which is m. I'm not sure if we are using 11gR2. Is there another way to do this without using WITH statement?

Comment: Since you're using `count(*) over()` you don't need the group by (the over() makes it a `window function`), try to remove the group by and see if it works for you

Comment: Hi again A.B. Cade, I think I am not being clear with my question here. But I what i need for the result of the first query is to be something like the second image. Is there by any chance I can do this without using Recursive CTEs?

Comment: Maybe with connect by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select * 
from your_data
start with instr(Wipdatavalue, '1') > 0
connect by level between regexp_substr(Wipdatavalue, '^\d+') 
and regexp_substr(Wipdatavalue, '\d+$')
```

It's a simplified example

The regexp_substr can be replaced with substr and instr if you like (may also be faster)

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d54e2/4)

Comment: Hello A.B. Cade, this one works fine except for the arrangement :) I wonder how we can address this.

Comment: @GianIsTheName, when you say arrangement, do you mean the order by? if so, try to add `order by regexp_substr(Wipdatavalue, '^\d+')`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Query**

```
select column_name, count(column_name)
from table
group by column_name
having count (column_name) > 1;
```